# Calling App Store Server API Get All Subscription Statuses production url always returns 401

Tags: ios, asp.net-core, testing, jwt, app-store-connect

I'm having a problem with communication between my backend server (written in net 6.0) and App Store Server API.

After finishing all related setups (setting up an API key, creating JWT), when calling [Get All Subscription Statuses](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_all_subscription_statuses) sandbox URL (https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com), I'm able to get HTTP 200 with the correct content of my subscription. But when I switch to the production URL (https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com), the request always returns HTTP 401 which specifies an invalid JWT.

Is there any difference between the sandbox and production's JWT? Do I need different API keys for each environment or am I missing any configs/setups?

Comment: were you able to make it solved? I am now getting the same issue when AppStoreServerAPIClient works correctly with Sandbox, but crashes with 401 in Production =(